# CCSprite gives the unpredictable result?

Tags: cocos2d-android

I am using the Cocos2d-android library

**Qus :**

***Image what I call from CCSprite.sprite("Star.png") , Sometime Appear correctly or Sometime randomly pick an Image from asset foler ?***

*Basically I am follow the Sample example which is in the library of cocos2d-android.*

Now, I have created a GameScene, In which 3 MenuItem like as sample example (Next, restart, previous)

*I have created different classes and extends the GameScene, when One class done their functionality after 5 sec I call the next class and previous disappear and new class appear on the same CClayer.*

from class A to class B it'll take 5 sec and in this time intervel I call a CCSprite for completing its class A. This Image (CCSPrite ) create problem otherwise all images working fine.

**What happen I don't know. Even I cleaup()  CCSprite before going into the class B.**

If someone face this problem than help me

All Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two resources of the same name STAR.png. Check all the drawable folders. Like there are 5 folders in res folder of the project like Drawable HDPI, drawable IDPI and so on. check all the folders for duplicate images.

Comment: I added all png file in Asset folder.

Comment: I checked all the Images , nothing is duplicated

Comment: Is this possible like : Before I'll call the Class B , I want to remove class A all the CCSprite

Comment: you question is very confusing..try to put some code pieces so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: I just create a new project and the same code run perfect ally

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move from one scene to another scene use this line.This will automatically remove  your all children.

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(gamePlayScene);
```

if you want to move from one layer to another with in the scene then remove that layer by using

```
this.removeSelf();
parentlayer.addChild(nextLayer);
```

Comment: I a m not changing CCScene. It's like change all the images from the Scene. Have you looked on the cocos2d android test sample. Just like that

Comment: are u getting random images for particular sprite or the same sprite is showing multiple times? If possible place the code

Comment: I have CCSprite which I used for 5 sec as I mention above that CCSprite have a smily symbol. when I complete with Class A functionality, it'll appear but sometime this CCSprite shown me the smily symbol and sometime shown the other images like which are in the Asset folder. I cant figure out this problem. the Code is very large right now. If it is possible to me than I reduce the code and will be pasted here.

Comment: What i can suggest you is:

Comment: What i can suggest you is: run an action parallel action ((remove all childern of classA and add Loading image in a sequence action.) && and then call classB)

Comment: have you used a test sample which is included into the cocos2d android .

Comment: actually I tried all this , but couldnot resolve it , if u used that test sample than suggest me what I add into my code